# Close a windows form then refresh another form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am trying to write a program that adds stock to a database,

The program wokrs to add stock and show stock, the issue im having is that when i clsoe my add stock form i would like to refresh the main form to show the new current stock state.

```
    this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(AddStock_FormClosing);

    private void AddStock_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Program.FORM1.ShowStock();
        MessageBox.Show("Tries to close");
        this.Close();
    }
```

When i close the form i get the message box so i know its getting to that point, my problem is that the message box keeps reopening and does not actually close the form.

Comment: What happens if you remove `this.Close()` as it's already closing, so you don't need to tell it to close again.

Comment: Ok, so this may be a problem with my Program.FORM1.ShowStock() line as if i comment this out and change the this.Close to this.Hide the form closes.                                                                                                 My problem is not that on my program.cs the public static Form1 FORM1; is never assigned and will always have a null value, is this something you know how i can make work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormClosing` event is fired every time the `Close` method is called.
If you don't cancel the closing event, the form will be closed and that's it. You don't need to call again `this.Close()`.

This is enough.

```
this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(AddStock_FormClosing);

private void AddStock_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Program.FORM1.ShowStock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using the Messagebox.Show in the wrong context.  Drop the Messagebox AFTER the this.close() and you'll find that it should be all good..

```
private void AddStock_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Program.FORM1.ShowStock();
        this.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Tries to close");

    }
```

What I would do is change the message box for the confirmation message asking to close or not.  Then Id use an IF statement to ascertain whether the return choice is true or not, then close the form and perform garbage collection (If necessary) if the confirmation returns false, return to the form without doing anything..